# Objects won't showup in render view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I can't find the solutions for this one. Basically the object are not showing up when I switch to render view ( the legs in cycles , the round base in Blender render )

[image]

Comment: Also you need to pick "one" render engine or the other.

Comment: I tried everything that was mentioned inthe linked topic, cycles render. Nothing seems to work

Comment: You can't render in both render modes at the same time in the same scene. This is expected behavior.

Comment: I was modeling in cycles and when I turned on the render view, you could only see the thing you see in the picture. Then I tested if it's same in blender render...

Comment: You have several objects parented to those armatures. Expand them in the outliner (use the plus sign, at the left of the armature icon) and make sure that the eye and camera icon are enabled for each of the "missing" objects.

Comment: nop, still nothing everything is visible only when I switch to render view . I tried appending those legs to a new project, they still didn't show up

Comment: I turned off the armature and it displayed the objects but i still don't understand how it works

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand your scene. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: Try to go into edit mode and select the parts that are not rendering press w and then click on flip normal's and if that doesn't help then I think you must explain your question bit more and some more images regarding your problem would help and you can also upload your blend file so that others may inspect it to rectify your problem and sorry for wrong answer because I couldn't understand your problem properly.